# How to fill attribute on the same line that v-for is used?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a simple loop with `Vue` that iterates over an array of objects an fills table rows.

```
<tr v-for="user in users">
  <td>{user.name}</td>
  <td>{user.id}</td>
</tr>
```

But I also want to fill a data attribute on the `<tr>` but when I do

```
<tr v-for="user in users" data-id="user.id">
```

It outputs

```
<tr data-id="user.id">
```

How can I fill the `data` attribute correctly with a `v-for` ?

Comment: Just like you do with any other attribute binding, with [`v-bind`](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#v-bind-Shorthand) directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing `v-bind`

```
<tr v-for="user in users" v-bind:data-id="user.id">
```

or shortcut form

```
<tr v-for="user in users" :data-id="user.id">
```

Comment: Great, will accept when it lets me. On another note, am I correct in assuming there is no shortcut for `v-for` ? Took a quick search and couldn't see it.